# re-assemble out-of-date raid5?

Tags: raid, mdadm, raid-5

I need help with my raid5 after it crashed through bad sectors.
Previously I could re-assemble it with

```
# mdadm --assemble --force -v /dev/md0 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdh1 /dev/sdi1
```

but while doing a backup it crashed again and now I'm not able to re-assemble it anymore because two disks are out-of-date:

```
# mdadm --assemble --force -v /dev/md0 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdh1 /dev/sdi1
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: /dev/sde1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot -1.
mdadm: /dev/sdf1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdg1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdh1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sdi1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 3.
mdadm: added /dev/sdg1 to /dev/md0 as 1
mdadm: added /dev/sdh1 to /dev/md0 as 2 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdi1 to /dev/md0 as 3 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: failed to add /dev/sde1 to /dev/md0: Device or resource busy
mdadm: added /dev/sdf1 to /dev/md0 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md0 assembled from 2 drives - not enough to start the array.
```

As you can see here only two devices **sdf1** and **sdg1** have set the latest update time (+ spare, but it's not finished rebuilding).

```
 mdadm --examine /dev/sd[efghi]1 | egrep 'dev|Update|Role|State|Chunk Size'
/dev/sde1:
          State : clean
    Update Time : Sun May 10 04:15:59 2015
     Chunk Size : 512K
   Device Role : spare
   Array State : AA.. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdf1:
          State : clean
    Update Time : Sun May 10 04:15:59 2015
     Chunk Size : 512K
   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA.. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdg1:
          State : clean
    Update Time : Sun May 10 04:15:59 2015
     Chunk Size : 512K
   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA.. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdh1:
          State : clean
    Update Time : Sat May  9 23:10:06 2015
     Chunk Size : 512K
   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

/dev/sdi1:
          State : active
    Update Time : Sat Dec  7 12:43:00 2013
     Chunk Size : 512K
   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

I did not change any data on the raid since the update time from the other two devices **sdh1** and **sdi1**. I don't need to resync all data, I just need to backup the last files, so I just need to mount it a last time read-only.

Is there any way to do this? Maybe I can force it to ignore the out-of-date? I'm wondering why *--force* doesn't work anymore...

Complete information to the raid5 devices:

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/sd[efghi]1
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : a87dfb70:2ecd03f9:ee62b434:fc637218
           Name : m08002-lin:data2gb
  Creation Time : Mon Sep  2 12:48:02 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 5860145664 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906763776 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 624d3873:7970ba27:da0f511a:45367bdd

    Update Time : Sun May 10 04:15:59 2015
       Checksum : 599a5235 - correct
         Events : 108804

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : spare
   Array State : AA.. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdf1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : a87dfb70:2ecd03f9:ee62b434:fc637218
           Name : m08002-lin:data2gb
  Creation Time : Mon Sep  2 12:48:02 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 5860145664 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906763776 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 4827a499:12980366:0de13b87:541a9b5e

    Update Time : Sun May 10 04:15:59 2015
       Checksum : ac5a08f2 - correct
         Events : 108804

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA.. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdg1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : a87dfb70:2ecd03f9:ee62b434:fc637218
           Name : m08002-lin:data2gb
  Creation Time : Mon Sep  2 12:48:02 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 5860145664 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906763776 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 8c959d62:3b9c1eac:6f8d7d92:13454ab4

    Update Time : Sun May 10 04:15:59 2015
       Checksum : 1c5f5282 - correct
         Events : 108804

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA.. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdh1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : a87dfb70:2ecd03f9:ee62b434:fc637218
           Name : m08002-lin:data2gb
  Creation Time : Mon Sep  2 12:48:02 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 5860145664 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906763776 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : df6b9eab:ea3c6e3a:47858e6d:1eb0783d

    Update Time : Sat May  9 23:10:06 2015
       Checksum : 57f1e4b2 - correct
         Events : 108796

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdi1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : a87dfb70:2ecd03f9:ee62b434:fc637218
           Name : m08002-lin:data2gb
  Creation Time : Mon Sep  2 12:48:02 2013
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 3906764800 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
     Array Size : 5860145664 (5588.67 GiB 6000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 3906763776 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262064 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : fbc64ec7:a97a36c1:69cc3812:37878af1

    Update Time : Sat Dec  7 12:43:00 2013
       Checksum : 507acca4 - correct
         Events : 83904

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could access my raid and backup my files!!

First I removed the spare device. Then I checked the other devices. There were two devices with bad sectors and I knew that the raid will crash again while resyncing when it wants to read or write to bad sectors.
So I decided to clear the raid and build up a new degraded raid that is not syncing and still has access to all previous data. I cleared all superblocks and created the raid leaving out one damaged device with

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md127 (or /dev/md0)
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sd[efgh]1
mdadm --create /dev/md127 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 --assume-clean /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1 missing
```

Important is the original order of the devices for the original raid and to create the new raid in the same order as well as to use the parameter *--assume-clean*!
You can get the original order with

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sd[efghi]1
```

Have a look at **Device Role**.

After re-creating the raid using assume-clean I could mount md127 and access all data directly without doing anything else.