# Reassemble RAID0 array despite error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, raid, hardware-failure

My ancient Synology CS407 was setup (deliberately) with RAID0 and I didn't have a backup system set up yet. There are four 1TB drives making a 4TB volume. One drive had a failure which led to the on-board software refusing to use/mount the volume at all. I understand that this is a serious fault and that in general the volume across all 4 drives has a failure, as there is no redundancy with RAID0. Nevertheless I would like to try to reassemble the array on Ubuntu, ignore the error/skip the bad data and see what state the volume is in. Not surprisingly, I am having trouble with the one disk that failed. Ubuntu sees its partition table, and reports one bad sector.

Here is the result of `/proc/mdstat`

```
Personalities : 
md2 : inactive dm-3[3](S) dm-2[2](S) dm-1[1](S) dm-0[0](S)
      3901770794 blocks super 1.1
       
unused devices: <none>
```

And `mdadm --examine --scan`

```
ARRAY /dev/md/2  metadata=1.1 UUID=442ee8f0:7c679b96:de0a0544:f72b1167 name=2
```

The LVM data is on partition 3 of each disk. Reassembling with `mdadm --assemble --run --force --verbose /dev/md2 /dev/sd[cdef]3` does this:

```
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md2
mdadm: /dev/sdc3 is identified as a member of /dev/md2, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdd3 is identified as a member of /dev/md2, slot 32769.
mdadm: /dev/sde3 is identified as a member of /dev/md2, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sdf3 is identified as a member of /dev/md2, slot 3.
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 1 of /dev/md2
mdadm: added /dev/sde3 to /dev/md2 as 2
mdadm: added /dev/sdf3 to /dev/md2 as 3
mdadm: added /dev/sdc3 to /dev/md2 as 0
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md2: Invalid argument
mdadm: Not enough devices to start the array.
```

This gives me a useless `/dev/md2`, shown as a RAID device in Ubuntu. I have to `stop` it before I can try reassembly again. What seems strange is the slot number for `/dev/sdd3`.

I've two more things that I could try, I'm looking for advice on whether either one is likely to help:

- Failing and removing `/dev/sdd3` and then adding it back
- I have a spare 1TB disk. I could make a disk copy with `dd` and fail the old disk and add in the new one. I'm just wondering if I make a sector by sector copy, will the new disk have any higher chances of success? Will it try it based on the different UUID?

EDIT - output of `mdadm --examine /dev/sdd3`:

```
/dev/sdd3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.1
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 442ee8f0:7c679b96:de0a0544:f72b1167
           Name : 2
  Creation Time : Sun Feb 13 00:14:43 2022
     Raid Level : raid0
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 1950885397 (930.25 GiB 998.85 GB)
    Data Offset : 8 sectors
   Super Offset : 0 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 23292ce9:221ebbfa:ea131c60:7888bc0c

    Update Time : Sun Feb 20 19:02:34 2022
       Checksum : e4ebe933 - correct
         Events : 1

     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 32769
   Array State : A.AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Comment: Don't use dd, use ddrescue to try copy a bad disk (and copy the whole disk, not the partition).   If you copy the disk the  metadata for the partition the UUID will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is not serious problem. This is catastrophic problem. RAID0 (when used as stripping RAID) store chinks of data to all the drives. So parts of one file can be located on all 4 disks.
If the information is very valuable you can try to contact specialized companies which may recovery some information. But this may cost a fortune.

There is small probability the RAID is use concatenating algorithm to create array. In such case you may recover good amount of information. But again this is not home task.

Comment: While I agree that this is a serious failure, per my answer there are things that can be tried to get the data back "as a home task".    The other thing - MDADM does not use a Concatenating algorythm to create an array, it uses stripes - That would be JBOD (I don't think that mdadm does JBOD, however LVM can do it)

Comment: @davidgo, about concatenating - just give idea/option to the OP to check. I am not aware of commercial product which use concatenation :( About home task - if one of disks from RAID0 fail I doubt anything other than the backup will help.

Comment: Thanks guys for your empathy! The drive is holding captured DV tapes. In the worst case I will have to recapture them. In the best case I rescue most of it and only have to recapture one tape. Certainly nothing that justifies high costs with a disk forensics expert :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how solvable this problem is.

The first thing I would attempt would be to turn off the Synology, remove the failed drive, then use ddrescue on a Linux box to clone that drive as best I can.   I would then put the cloned drive in the synology.

You might then be able to "force assemble" the array.  I've never had to try it, but maybe with a command like

```
mdadm --force --assemble /dev/md2 /dev/sdc3 /dev/sdd3 /dev/sde3 /dev/sdf3
```

The key being, according to the LUKS MAN page that (for an Assemble)

> "--force
> Assemble  the  array  even  if the metadata on some devices appears to be out-of-date.  If mdadm
> cannot find enough working devices to start the array,  but  can  find  some  devices  that  are
> recorded  as  having failed, then it will mark those devices as working so that the array can be
> started. This works only for native. For external metadata it allows  to  start  dirty  degraded
> RAID  4,  5, 6.  An array which requires --force to be started may contain data corruption.  Use
> it carefully.""

You could possibly do this without doing a ddrescue - but you are going from making life difficult to making it very difficult by trying to work on a drive with a hardware failure.

You should not trust your data.  There is likely corruption/inconsistency somewhere.

If this fails, you may be able to get bits of your data off the remaining good drives by using photorec or equivalent.

Comment: Looking again at your output, we also need to work out how to change slot 32769 to slot 1.   (This is interesting, as I'm fairly sure 32769 = -1).  I wonder if you could fix this with mdadm --manage /dev/md2 --re-add  /dev/sdd3

Comment: I'll try this first, thanks

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't do much:
```mdadm --manage /dev/md2 --re-add /dev/sdd3
mdadm: Cannot get array info for /dev/md2```

Comment: Regarding the 32769, I've edited my answer to include the output of `mdadm --examine /dev/sdd3`- the line `Device Role : Active device 32769`- is there no way to edit this to make it think it is device 1 again?

Comment: I came across https://superuser.com/questions/912939/re-assemble-out-of-date-raid5 which seems to have fixed the problem for someone using RAID5.  Trying this is **extremely high risk** and the exact syntax would be different.  If you have nothing left to loose (or you can clone all 4 disks first - failing which backing up their superblocks) - maybe you can zero your superblocks and recrrate the device with assume-clean? (,of-course specifying RAID0) not RAID5.

Comment: As I did indeed have nothing to lose, I tried this and the volume, in terms of Ubuntu see a 4TB "drive" again as a RAID array, came back. However, the volume type was not recognised and after trying and failing to get it to mount, I gave up. I'm setting up from scratch and have a 4TB USB3 drive for backups.

Comment: Pitty you gave up. It was probably an LVM or ZFS filesystem - we may well have been able to take the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Your best chance would be to try to copy as much of the disk as possible to the new disk. Don't use `dd`, use `ddrescue`. `dd` will stop at the first error. I have restored almost complete disks with `ddrescue`, so it is possible to get most of the data back. `ddrescue` may take a long time.

Then, with the copied disk, try @davidgo's solution.

You have now experienced the disadvantages of raid 0. Unless you're really tight on disk space, consider moving to raid 5.